# Access VBA: Put values of a multi-select list box into a Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a list box where I can select Monday- Friday. I can select as many days as I want in the list box, all of them if I wanted. I want to know how to insert the value of the listbox into my table.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
Private Sub Command499_Click()
Set RstRecSet = Nothing
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim dateDay As String
Dim dateWeek As String
MsgBox (lstDateDay.Selected)
''dateWeek = lstDateWeek.Value

db.Execute " INSERT INTO tblContacts (DateDay, DateWeek)Values" & "('" & dateDay & "', '" & dateWeek & "');"
db.Close

End Sub
```

As you can see I've been trying a lot of different things. My problem is getting the value of the list box; it keeps showing as null even though it has data selected. The exact error I'm getting is:

> "Invalid use of Null."

EDIT:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblContacts")
For Each itm In lstDateWeek.ItemsSelected
    rs.AddNew
    rs!dateWeek = lstDateWeek.ItemData(itm)
    rs!dateDay = itm
    rs.Update
Next
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

`dateDay` and `dateWeek` are columns in `tblContacts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the ItemsSelected collection to get the index of the selected items in the Multi Select list box and then iterate through them and use the index to reference the rows stored in the ItemData collection. As part of this iteration simply create a record set and add the fields and update.  There are different ways to handle this part but I like this one shown below.

To use my sample, simply create a table called tblTest and two columns Description (text) and Day as a number.
Create a form and add a multi-select list box named DaysOfWeek.  fill it in with the days of the week as a ValueList and then add a button which I labeled Store.

Paste the following code into the buttons click event and try it

```
Dim db As Database
   Dim rs As Recordset

   Set db = CurrentDb()
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblTest")
   For Each itm In DaysOfWeek.ItemsSelected
        rs.AddNew
        rs!Description = DaysOfWeek.ItemData(itm)
        rs!Day = itm
        rs.Update
  Next
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
```

My event procedure looks like this:

```
Private Sub Command19_Click()
   Dim db As Database
   Dim rs As Recordset

   Set db = CurrentDb()
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblTest")
   For Each itm In DaysOfWeek.ItemsSelected
        rs.AddNew
        rs!Description = DaysOfWeek.ItemData(itm)
        rs!Day = itm
        rs.Update
  Next
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

This could be done with an ADO call by building a SELECT string for your INSERT statement as well but for me this is straightforward..  If you have any questions let me know.  If I can figure out how to attach my sample database I will.

Comment: btw if You store itm as I did you will see it is actually a value correspondiing to the row number and it is zero-based just FYI

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, very informative! I converted your gode to my purpose. It's stepping through but not adding to my table. I'll put the code in my op.

Comment: I saw how you modified my code.  That should work and update the table of course I'm assuming this table is an Access table.  There is one thing I have thought of though.  

I was wondering If you have the table open while you are testing this code you may need to close it and reopen it to see the updates.  An open table won't reflect any data changes in the underlying recordset.  I have made that mistake once or twice.  If you feel it helped you please mark it as an answer btw.  Thanks much.

Comment: Hey David,
So you where right. The table just took a bit to update. However this only adds one week day. If i click thursday and friday itll only add friday, the last record.

Comment: If you want to add the data as you click on the multi-select list box, you would need to add some logic to keep previously entered items from being added again.  I used a button because then I can hold the control key down, click multiple items and then click the button to add all the values at one time.  That iteration should add each one separately.  If you can post your form, table and code in a sample database somewhere that I can access I would be more than happy to take a look at it.  Also make sure your list box is set to Simple or Extended in the multi-select property just to be sure.

Comment: David, I'm not sure if your still monitoring this thread or not but in regards to your previous  comment. I am still working on this issue. The problem is I'm not sure how to pull the data back out onto the form.

Comment: or example, if I were to click monday wednesday friday. In recCount it would add a 3 and it date week it would add friday. I would like the data to not just be entered into my table but also retrievable by a form. so I have a search function that displays recordsets back into the forms. No if i take my recordset and try to fill my list box with the data i've added with this code will it fill up all the correct data or just friday? Personally i'm thinking I might have to cycle through this data recCount to get the proper info displayed.

Comment: If I understand you correctly.  If you are storing the data from the list box into a table you would also have to store it with a key that matches the form record for each selection so that you can query the table to retrieve the data on the form that matches the key value for the record displayed on the form.